# Magento2 - Exception occurs when I update customer data using customer repository

Tags: magento2, module, customer-attribute, repository, customer-update

**Error:**
Invalid value of **UK** provided for the `countryId` field.

**Error File:**
`vendor\\magento\\module-customer\\Model\\ResourceModel\\AddressRepository.php`

**Error line:**
133

**Code is:**

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getId());
$cattrValue = $customer->getCustomAttribute('username');
$customer->setCustomAttribute('username', $customerData['web_username']);

$customer->setFirstname($customerData['first_name']);
$customer->setLastname($customerData['last_name']);

$this->customerRepository->save($customer, $hashedPassword);
```

Comment: Country ID should be GB. But as you are not upding it the address must already be in the DB. You will have to update UK to GB via direct SQL https://gist.github.com/pitbulk/ff028a9ba472ed810e54a976d583ef88

Comment: Hey @DominicXigen convert this comment to an answer

Comment: Hey @DominicXigen, you are right. It saved my day. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Country ID should be GB. But as you are not upding it the address must already be in the DB. You will have to update UK to GB via direct SQL

http://gist.github.com/pitbulk/ff028a9ba472ed810e54a976d583ef88